# Using PowerShell in c#

Tags: c#, powershell

So basically im running a script to receive the IP adress of computer, date and time an account is locked out at work and to do this im making a small gui so all the network technicians can use it, my code Currently goes

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var username = textBox1.Text;
        using (var powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            try
            {
                powerShellInstance.AddScript(
                    "Get-WinEvent -ComputerName COMPUTERNAMEHERE -FilterHashtable @{logname=LOGNAMEHERE;id=IDHERE;data=" +
                    username + "} |" +
                    "Select-Object -Property timecreated, " +
                    "@{label='computername';expression={$_.properties[6].value.Split(':')[3]}} " +

                    "Get-WinEvent -ComputerName COMPUTERNAMEHERE -FilterHashtable @{logname=LOGNAMEHERE;id=IDHERE;data=" +
                    username + "} | " +
                    "Select-Object -Property timecreated, " +
                    "@{label='computername';expression={$_.properties[6].value.Split(':')[3]}} " +

                    "Get-WinEvent -ComputerName COMPUTERNAMEHERE -FilterHashtable @{logname=LOGNAMEHERE;id=IDHERE;data=" +
                    username + "} | " +
                    "Select-Object -Property timecreated, " +
                    "@{label='computername';expression={$_.properties[6].value.Split(':')[3]}} ");



                // invoke execution on the pipeline (collecting output)
                Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = powerShellInstance.Invoke();

                // loop through each output object item
                foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
                {
                    // if null object was dumped to the pipeline during the script then a null
                    // object may be present here. check for null to prevent potential NRE.
                    if (outputItem != null)
                    {
                        listView1.Items.Add(OUTPUTHERE);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                listView1.Items.Add("Failed");
            }

        }
```

but it currently crashes on the part of code where i invoke it, I've never worked on power shell before so any help would be appreciated and im really sorry if this is a stupid question xD

Comment: What do you mean by crahsing? What is the Exception wich is being thrown?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.ParseException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll

Additional information: System error.

Comment: That looks like your Powershell script is malformed and can't be parsed. 

At a small look, the closing bracket after "-ComputerName)" in your very first line doesnt seem to be correct

Comment: Okay so its now running but it isnt returning any values

Comment: If you can't get the powershell to work you might want to look at the [System.DirectoryServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.